# PHP json_decode thrown an error for validate json string

Tags: php, json

I have following error

```
Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in action.php
```

while posted json has validated (by jsonLint.com validation).

Here is my json string:

```
[
{
    "eTGid": "1",
    "eTid": "34",
    "evrakGelisTarihi": "12/12/2013",
    "evrakKonu": "Sertifika denemesi",
    "evrakKurumID": "1047",
    "evrakCikisTarihi": "13/12/2013",
    "evrakCikisSayisi": "313213213213",
    "aciklamaBolumu": "açıklayıcı notlar",
    "gelenEvrakTarihi": "30/12/2013",
    "gelenEvrakSayisi": "3132321",
    "gelenEvrakEtakipNo": "987654",
    "bagliIlaclar": "[\"0\",\"[{\\\"ilacID\\\":\\\"744\\\",\\\"ilacPN\\\":\\\"asdasd2132\\\",\\\"ilacSKT\\\":\\\"12/12/2013\\\"}]\"]",
    "bagliFirmalar": "[\"0\",\"[{\\\"firmaID\\\":\\\"1047\\\"}]\"]",
    "": "[\"0\",\"[{\\\"bankaID\\\":\\\"5\\\",\\\"makbuzNO\\\":\\\"asdasda\\\",\\\"makbuzTARIHI\\\":\\\"12/12/2013\\\",\\\"ihracaatYapilacakUlkeID\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"ilacIhracADI\\\":\\\"ABFADER\\\",\\\"makbuzTUTAR\\\":\\\"202,06\\\",\\\"makbuzTipDetayDEGERİ\\\":\\\"10\\\"}]\",\"[{\\\"bankaID\\\":\\\"5\\\",\\\"makbuzNO\\\":\\\"ASDAWW\\\",\\\"makbuzTARIHI\\\":\\\"12/12/2013\\\",\\\"ihracaatYapilacakUlkeID\\\":\\\"191\\\",\\\"ilacIhracADI\\\":\\\"ABFADEX\\\",\\\"makbuzTUTAR\\\":\\\"202,06\\\",\\\"makbuzTipDetayDEGERİ\\\":\\\"9\\\"}]\"]",
    "bagliMakbuzlar": "[\"0\",\"987654»12/12/2013»3213213\"]",
    "kurumIcimi": "hayir"
}
]
```

and my php code is:

```
$gelenJsonVerisi = $_POST['yeniEvrak'];
echo($gelenJsonVerisi);
$yeniEvrakObj = json_decode($gelenJsonVerisi);

exit($yeniEvrakObj->{'eTGid'});
```

Where did I go wrong?

After suggestions:

1. My Json string has arrived to the serverside  (php) as an array (between brackets).
2. Array has only one element (member) that it is our json string (object)
3. Handle the arrays first element and assign it to a php object and deal with it.

   ```
   $gelenJsonVerisi = $_POST['yeniEvrak'];
   $yeniEvrakObjArray = json_decode($gelenJsonVerisi,TRUE);
   $yeniEvrakObj = $yeniEvrakObjArray[0];
   exit($yeniEvrakObj['eTGid']); // one of sample value
   ```

   Thank you

Comment: Could you post your script's output?

Comment: That's an object **inside an array**, not just a plain object. Use `var_dump`.

Comment: Hello @OscarPérez all output is json string and error message. I wrote them above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string shows an array, that contains a single object. access the data like so:

```
$yeniEvrakObj = json_decode($gelenJsonVerisi);
echo $yeniEvrakObj[0]->eTGid;
```

If you're sure there's but 1 object inside that array, you *could* try:

```
$yeniEvrakObj = json_decode(
                    substr($gelenJsonVerisi,1,-1)
);
```

Which chops off the leading and terminating brackets. This implies no leading of trailing whitespace, so `trim` the string first.

[check codepad](http://codepad.org/AjjWb8k7). As you can see, the `json_decode` call returns the data as an array containing an object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [eTGid] => 1
            [eTid] => 34
            [evrakGelisTarihi] => 12/12/2013
            [evrakKonu] => Sertifika denemesi
            [evrakKurumID] => 1047
            [evrakCikisTarihi] => 13/12/2013
            [evrakCikisSayisi] => 313213213213
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$gelenJsonVerisi = $_POST['yeniEvrak'];
echo($gelenJsonVerisi);
$yeniEvrakObj = json_decode($gelenJsonVerisi);
exit($yeniEvrakObj[0]->eTGid);
```

Comment: Faster than me. Congrats!

Comment: print_r make no change of output :(

Comment: ya i thought it as array

Comment: @ArunKillu , Elias Van Ootegem explain this above. Also thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `json_decode` throwing the error, it's when you try to access the resulting *array*. Yes, that's right, *array*. Your JSON value is this:

```
[ { ... } ]
^  array  ^
```

So you need to access the result like:

```
$yeniEvrakObj[0]->eTGid
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the way you're trying to access to the decoded object, as it is inside an array.
Your code should be:

```
$gelenJsonVerisi = $_POST['yeniEvrak'];
echo($gelenJsonVerisi);
$yeniEvrakObj = json_decode($gelenJsonVerisi);

exit($yeniEvrakObj[0]->eTGid);
```

Edit: Thanks for the comments on this answer that made me see I was mistaken

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I suspect you were down-voted because `$obj->{'string'}` or `$obj->string` doesn't make a difference in this case, it's because the JSON string is an array

Comment: I see... my fault, excuseme

Comment: No need for appologies, just delet/edit your answer to correct your mistake.